return a value from a Java agent / JAR file to lotusScript
have this Java code :
public class PdfByteReader {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filePath = args[0];
        try {
            String pdfContent = readPdfFileByteByByte(filePath);
            System.out.println(pdfContent);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("ERROR" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static String readPdfFileByteByByte(String filePath) throws IOException {
        File pdfFile = new File(filePath);
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pdfFile)) {
            int byteRead;
            while ((byteRead = fis.read()) != -1) {
                content.append((char) byteRead);
            }
        }

        return content.toString();
    }
    
}

i can build a JAR file or create a Java Agent in a Lotus Notes app, but : how can i receive from lotus script the return value of this (string)?
i'm trying to parse a pdf file into string in order to upload to a API

Do you want to run your code locally, i.e. in a Notes client? You can use Java from LotusScript using LS2J, pass parameters to Java as well, and return simple values or use a document as interface. So you would have your Java code in a Java script library that you can attach to from LotusScipt. Or you can build everything as a Java agent.
See https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/12.0.0/basic/LSAZ_USING_LS2J.html

Don't do it in LotusScript if possible.
If you have your java agent, add something like this:
public static void postPdfString(String pdfString) {
    String endpointUrl = "https://api.myexample.com/pdfuploadendpoint";
    
    try {
        URL url = new URL(endpointUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        byte[] out = pdfString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(out.length);
        try (OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream()) {
            os.write(out);
        }
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            System.out.println("PDF uploaded successfully.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to upload PDF. Response code: " + responseCode);
        }
        connection.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

You can then pass your pdfString and post it to the end point.
